# Run a count query for every row ID in results

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to count the number of cars at each parking lot in my app, along with some other info. But, I'm not too sure how to approach this.

**Tables**

I have 3 tables.

- `lot` - this table contains information for a parking lot
- `manager` - this table contains information for a parking lot's manager
- `car` - this table has a list of cars that can be at a given parking lot

```
lot
 id | name | manager_id
----+------+------------
  1 | foo  | 1
  2 | bar  | 1

manager
 id | name
----+--------
  1 | alice
  2 | bob

car
 id | lot_id
----+--------
  1 | 1
  2 | 1
  3 | 2
  4 | 2
```

**Desired output**

Given a `manager_id`, I want a list of:

- the name of the lot they manage
- the name of the manager
- the number of cars in that lot

This is what I want to end up with.

```
 id | lot_name | manager_id | manager_name | num_cars
----+----------+------------+--------------+----------
  1 | foo      | 1          | alice        | 2
  2 | bar      | 1          | alice        | 2
```

I've figured out how to get the manager name in the results, but I'm not sure how to get the number of cars for each lot.

This is what I have so far.

```
-- manager_id 1 is alice.

select
    id, name as lot_name, manager_id,
    (select name from manager where id = 1) as manager_name
from lot where manager_id = 1;
```

I'm thinking I need a join somewhere to bring in the `car` table and somehow do a `count`. Not exactly sure how though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if i understood correctly are you referring to a group by?

```
SELECT lot.id,lot.name,manager.id,manager.name,count(car.id)
FROM lot
LEFT JOIN manager ON lot.manager_id = manager.id
LEFT JOIN car ON car.lot_id = lot.id
GROUP BY lot.id,lot.name,manager.id,manager.name;
```

Comment: Yep! Okay, cool. Looks like I gotta study `group by` more.